# C# board game showing number of hearts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop

```
MessageBox.Show("You are wrong");
noOfhearts = noOfhearts - 1;
if (noOfhearts == 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Game Over! You score " + score);
    Hide();
}
else 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= noOfhearts; i++) 
    {
        heart[i].Visible = true;
        //I have 3 heart pcitureboxes "heart1" "heart2" "heart3"
    }
}
```

I want the game to show the number of hearts that the user has and when they get a question wrong they should lose a heart. If the user has 0 hearts the game will end. I have 3 difficulties in this game, easy starts with 3 hearts, medium 2, and hard with 1. This makes it awkward because depending on the difficulty the user will have a different number of hearts. That is why I tried using a for loop but obviously what follows is just stupid and I thought it was worth a try.

Comment: Not a clue as to what you are asking here.  Please clarify.

Comment: so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: you could set the initial number of hearts to the difficulty (so if its hard set it to 1 at the beginning) and then proceed like you are doing now

Comment: What is the question here? Is your code not giving expected ouput? What is expected out put? Are you getting any error or exception? Can you explain logc og your code?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like you are asking us to do your homework.

Comment: inside the for loop isn't correct as it doesn't recognize that im trying to add "i" to "heart" to reference the picturebox.

Comment: this is a small snippet of code i have been working on for a few weeks with +400 lines of code

Comment: What does "isn't correct" mean? What doesn't it recognize? **Be more specific**.

Comment: From the [on-topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without more detail about what you are using to make this game. Visual studio... are you using Unity?  Either way, in your else{}, i noticed that you arent setting the hearts > the number of hearts visible to invisible. You'd need to add that if you want them to not be displayed.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= totalHeartNumber; i++) 
            {
                if(i <= noOfHearts) {
                   heart[i].Visible = true;
                   //I have 3 heart pcitureboxes "heart1" "heart2" "heart3"
                 } else {
                   heart[i].Visible = false;
                 }
       }
```

Youd need to set totalHeartNumber = to the number of hearts for that difficulty. It's just another if statement used when you are setting up your game difficulty.

Also, if you aren't instantiating these dynamically based on difficulty level, you will need the MAX number of hearts there at all times (whatever is the max number of hearts you can have in any difficulty), and just have them invisible if they arent required.